# Make a validation with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I am new in javascript. I want a validation on my checkbox. I have this html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="acceptTerms"/>
<input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="Enter now" title="Enter now" />
```

When you submit, and you not select the checkbox. The checkbox must get the class "error". When you check the checkbox. Than the form must be sumit. How can make that with jQuery / js?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function(e){
    var $check = $('input[name=acceptTerms]');
    if (!$check.is(':checked')) {
       $check.addClass('error');
       e.preventDefault()
    }
})

$('input[name=acceptTerms]').change(function(){
     if (this.checked) $(this).removeClass('error')
})
```